# Non-telepathic child is considered a monster by post-nuclear-war telepathic humans

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a post-nuclear-war story where humans have mutated to have telepathic abilities. Institutionalized child (non-telepathic genetic throwback) has no volume control to his thoughts and "normal" telepaths hear his angry thoughts as mental screams and consider him a "monster."

At the beginning of the story you don't know he is a little boy; the nurses talk of him as a hideous monster that they loathe to interact with.

People still talk verbally.  He is kept at a hospital and they want to euthanize him; his mother kidnaps him but brings him back telling them to kill him, "He's a monster!"

Maybe read  in an anthology collection for high school English class - 1970's publication date?

Comment: Do you remember when you read it last? When it might have been published? Was it in an physical book or online?

Comment: Are you sure it is his thoughts they hear? Could it instead be his actual voice, which no one uses any more?

Comment: This sounds similar, but not quite like Chrysalids, by John Wyndham.

Comment: I also recall this story, but not the title. The boy's mother tries to argue that the boy's non-telepathy is a survival trait, since he cannot be controlled by telepathic means. The boy is euthanized in the end because his violent thoughts cause great pain to the telepaths, and he cannot be disciplined to control his thoughts: no "spankings" by telepathy for him.